# Require npm module with browserify cannot find dependency

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify

I'm new to using Node JS modules and I'm using some modules in the browser, which I'm bundling with browserify, to convert markdown text into HTML.

I have a .js file where I'm require-ing a module ('markdown-it') from npm. I'm running browserify to bundle the file to include it in the html page and this all works. My problem is when I want to add the ['markdown-it-latex'](https://www.npmjs.com/package/markdown-it-latex) plugin. I installed it using npm as the rest of the plugins (eg. 'markdown-it-sup'), but when I require it in the file and I run browserify on it, I get the error:

```
Error: Cannot find module './src/ParseError' from '/home/bianca/Documents/CS/supersecret/supersecret_/node_modules/katex/dist'
at /home/bianca/.nvm/versions/node/v7.5.0/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/browser-resolve/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:55:21
at load (/home/bianca/.nvm/versions/node/v7.5.0/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/browser-resolve/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:69:43)
at onex (/home/bianca/.nvm/versions/node/v7.5.0/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/browser-resolve/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:92:31)
at /home/bianca/.nvm/versions/node/v7.5.0/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/browser-resolve/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:22:47
at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:112:15)
```

Katex was installed via npm as a dependency of this module and I don't know where to search to find the problem. The src folder is actually not in katex/dist/, but in katex/, so I'm confused about why it looks for it in dist. I've been struggling with this for a while and I've started reading lots of Node tutorials to try to find the root cause, but so far I haven't had success so any help is much appreciated.

The README for markdown-it-latex prompts to installation via yarn, but there's also the possibility to install it via npm. From what I read it shouldn't be an issue there, but I might be missing something...

Update: I also tried installing via yarn and using import instead of require (as per the docs), together with babelify for ES6 imports and the same error popped up when running browserify.